# Loading mxgraph in react useEffect method problem

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, mxgraph

I try to show a mxgraph object after I upload a file to a server. The server runs [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) and returns the parsed data as JSON Object. I use Typescript to generate an Object out of my JSON result. This Object is set to a variable with react `useState`.

Now my problem:
after I set the diagram variable with `useState`, the `useEffect` is fired up. In the `useEffect` my goal is to show the mxgraph. **The Graph is shown, but it creates a new component every time the useEffect is Called and the graph appears in a new div**

My question is, is there a way crating the graph in the `useEffect` method and only showing it in the intended div?

**Component Header**

```
  const [diagram, setDiagram] = useState<IDiagram>();
  const divGraph = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

**The api call**

```
const onSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/upload", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });

      //create a TypeScript Object out of result
      var diag = diagramCreator.createDiagram(res.data);

      //sets the diagram variable with useState
      setDiagram(diag);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

**The useEffect**

```
useEffect(() => {

    if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported()) {
      mxUtils.error("Browser is not supported!", 200, false);
    } 

    else {

      const graph = new mxGraph(divGraph.current);
      graph.setConnectable(true);
      graph.setHtmlLabels(true);

      mxEvent.disableContextMenu(divGraph.current);

      if(typeof diagram !== 'undefined' ){

        var mxGraphCreator = new MxGraphCreator(graph,diagram);

        graph.getModel().beginUpdate();

        mxGraphCreator.start();

        graph.getModel().endUpdate();
      }
    }
  });
```

**the 'HTML' part**

```
  return(
    <Fragment>
    ...
        <div          
          className="graph-container"
          ref={divGraph}
          id="divGraph">
          </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
```

here you see the actual result:
[my goal is to show the orange diagram in the top 
turquoise area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaicT.png)

If you need more information please ask. Thanks

Comment: Please try this, in useEffect, add `return () => divGraph.current = null`, and as the second argument to useEffect pass an array with `diagram` as the first array item. You may need to change the typing in useRef.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mr. Robot, i tried you suggestions. But the ```divGraph.current``` property is readOnly so there is no way setting this to null. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Hi @FlorianSchmidt it is not readonly. Please see this: "If you want a mutable ref object that starts with a null value, make sure to also give | null to the generic argument. That will make it mutable, because you "own" it and not React." https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31065